# Angular 6 - Render a dropdown in child component after data is received from REST service in Parent Component

Tags: angular, angular6

Can you help me to render a dropdown (HTML Select) that is present in the child component after data is received in the Parent Component from an external REST service?
I tried doing it using @Input, however, the problem is that the child component is rendering even before the data is received from REST service and it does not render again after the data is received even using ngOnChanges hook.
Can you tell me the appropriate way to render this in Angular 6?
Thank you.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Comment: What have you tried. Can you post the code

Comment: Have you tried implementing dropdown with *ngIf="dataYouAreWaitingFor!=null" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)** Directive to instantiate the child-component after the subscription is resolved or when data is Available.

**Component-1**

```
 public response$:Observable<data[]>;
    constructor(public service:ShareService)
      {
          this.response$= this.service.getdata();

      }
```

**Component-1 Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="response$">
<hello [response]="response$"></hello>
</ng-container>
```

**Component-2**

```
export class HelloComponent  {
@Input() response:Observable<Idata[]>


}
```

**Component-2 Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (response|async)">
  {{item.body}}
<div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2tnus)**

if you don't want to use `async` pipe

```
public response:Array<data>=[];
        constructor(public service:ShareService)
          {
              this.service.getdata().subscribe(value=>this.response=value);

          }
```

**Component-1 Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="response">
<hello [response]="response"></hello>
</ng-container>
```

**Component-2**

```
export class HelloComponent  {
@Input() response:Array<data>


}
```

**Component-2 Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of response">
  {{item.body}}
<div>
```

Comment: Or pass the resolved observable <ng-container *ngIf="response$ | async as response">
<hello [response]="response"></hello>
</ng-container>

Comment: Hi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.